# Update multiple tables in mysql in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, sql-update

I have two tables `tbl1` and `tbl2` they are not related to each other.

I am doing two queries on these tables.

`UPDATE tbl1 SET exp = 1 WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4);`

`UPDATE tbl2 SET exp = 1 WHERE id IN(2,1,4,5);`

Now how can i make it more optimized ?

Comment: Why you want this ????

Comment: Down voted, because of the fact the question lacks information.

Comment: How about "Multiple-table syntax"? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html

Comment: To optimize...i have to update dozens of tbl1,tbl2.......tbl12 so doing in 12 queries can be too slow! @CricFavor

Comment: Did you check if your queries become slow?

Comment: Is `id` indexed?  If not, _that_ is the cause of the sluggishness.

Comment: `id` is indexed @RickJames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
UPDATE tbl1, tbl2
SET tbl1.exp = 1,
    tbl2.exp = 1
WHERE tbl1.id IN(1,2,3,4)
AND   tbl2.id IN(2,1,4,5)
```

Comment: Ya, but say if  `tbl2.id = 2` does not exists then the whole update does not works!!!

Comment: Yes it works only if all the ids specified inside `IN` are present if any `id` inside `IN` is does not exists in the table then it `affects zero rows` @Marvin

Comment: I tried it in the MySQL Workbench and it worked for me. Maybe a different issue?

Comment: @SlimShady select It as correct answer, because It working, If you decided to use other way It's your choice. Anyway good luck and happy coding!

Comment: If your IN clauses are long, I would expect this "cross join" to be terribly slow.

Comment: Yes `IN` is **long** @RickJames